# Lombok not working in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, lombok

I have eclipse version: "Mars Release (4.5.0)"

I have downloaded latest lombok jar from: https://projectlombok.org/download.html

I executed:

```
java -jar lombok.jar install $eclipseDir
```

After this I can see lombok.jar in my eclipse directory and eclipse.ini.

Restarted eclipse with:
eclipse -clean

But still lombok is not working for me.

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem. What helped was:

1. Restart Eclipse
2. Select from top menu Project -> Clean...
3. Clean all projects that use Lombok

If it will not help, try again from point 1. (I know it sounds stupid but it worked on my PC on second try.)

Also, I'm using Lombok version 1.16.4 (and Eclipse Mars of course)

BTW: Make sure that you have lombok.jar in the eclipse directory.

Comment: @Vivek: where exactly? About is huge in Eclipse

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4MDlI.png(see last line) Lombok text. It used to show for Juno.

Comment: I have this twice: Lombok v1.16.4 "Candid Duck" is installed. http://projectlombok.org/

Comment: Worked. Problem was I was using -vm option in eclipse.ini, and we need to use -vmargs if we are using -vm in eclipse.in.

Comment: That's also true. Part of my eclipse config: eclipse.vmargs=-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-javaagent:lombok.jar

Comment: Worked for me after cleaning all projects once - thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I have solved the same problem, here are my steps

1. check eclipse.ini, make sure lombok is properly installed
2. restart eclipse
3. project->clean, clean your project
4. **window->show view->problems, Ctrl+A to select ALL errors, right
   click & delete**
5. project->clean, clean your project again

I think that should work.

Comment: sorted out the problem in eclipse neon as per your instructions. And it worked

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue in Eclipse Neon.2 and in STS 3.8.3 the solution was

1. Download the Lombok jar from 
   https://projectlombok.org/download.html
2. Execute
   java -jar lombok.jar
3. Configure the Eclipse or STS and install.
   It will copy the lombok.jar under Eclipse dir and add the line -javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar in eclipse.ini or STS.ini
4. Make sure in About eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration 
   -javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar line exists
5. If it's a git project then delete the project from workspace and import the project again. or else export the project and then import it again
   Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

On mac os this is because the location of eclipse.ini has changed. Kepler and Luna used `Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini`. Mars uses `Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini.`

It looks like this has broken Lombok's Eclipse auto-detection as well.

Comment: Did you get this working?  I am having an issue whereby the lombok installer can't find eclipse even if I specify the location manually.

Comment: OK got it working, copy lombok.jar to `/sts-bundle/STS.app/Contents/MacOS`.  Then edit `sts-bundle/STS.app/Contents/Eclipse/STS.ini` and add the following line to the bottom of the file `-javaagent:lombok.jar`

Answer (score 4):

eclipse.ini edit and project clean

```
-vmargs
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

Comment: I have Eclipse Neon.1 on linux with several vmargs option in my eclipse.ini. Installer put lombok at the end, but it didn't work. After manual repositioning -javaagent:path_to_lombok.jar on top immediately after -vmargs it worked fine!

Answer (score 3):

run the jar- I just double clicked on it;
Add the following to eclipse .ini, and have lombok.jar in the eclipse folder

```
-vmargs
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

Windows 7 + eclipse mars

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04, when I jump into eclipse directory and run the executable there, it is ok, however when the launcher icon is used, the entire eclipse.ini is being ignored for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with Neon.  The problem was that the version of lombok.jar installed in the Eclipse directory was not the same as the version specified in pom.xml.